# MySQL random join

Tags: mysql, join, random

Here is my MySQL database:

[image]

And my query to get all subcategories:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`, `a`.`url_segment`, `a`.`categories_id`, `b`.`image` AS supplements_image
FROM (`subcategories` AS a)
LEFT JOIN `supplements` AS b ON `b`.`subcategories_id` = `a`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `reviews` AS c ON `c`.`supplements_id` = `b`.`id`
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`categories_id` ASC, COUNT(c.id) DESC, `b`.`image` ASC
```

The problem is with the subcategory image, that should be the image of a random product inside that subcategory, but I'm always getting the image of the first product. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`, `a`.`url_segment`, `a`.`categories_id`, 
        (SELECT `image` 
         FROM `supplements` 
         WHERE `subcategories_id` = `a`.`id` 
         ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
        ) AS supplements_image
FROM (`subcategories` AS a)
LEFT JOIN `reviews` AS c ON `c`.`supplements_id` = `a`.`id`
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`categories_id` ASC, COUNT(c.id) DESC
```

Edited unspecified alias `b` and now works great: [See fiddle!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba784/4)